# CognitoIdentityCredentials params Logins key for sign In with Apple ID?

Tags: aws-sdk-js

What value should be used for the Logins property of the parameters required to intialize the Cognito Credentials object (CognitoIdentityCredentials) if I need to support social login for Apple ID.

AWS documentation only lists the below keys

- Facebook: graph.facebook.com
- Google: accounts.google.com
- Amazon: www.amazon.com
- Twitter: api.twitter.com
- Digits: www.digits.com

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_CreateIdentityPool.html#API_CreateIdentityPool and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html

I can't find what should be used for Apple ID anywhere in the AWS documentation and the aws-sdk typescript does not list it as well - see below

```
    /**
     * A set of optional name-value pairs that map provider names to provider tokens. The available provider names for Logins are as follows:   Facebook: graph.facebook.com    Amazon Cognito user pool: cognito-idp.&lt;region&gt;.amazonaws.com/&lt;YOUR_USER_POOL_ID&gt;, for example, cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_123456789.    Google: accounts.google.com    Amazon: www.amazon.com    Twitter: api.twitter.com    Digits: www.digits.com   
     */
    Logins?: LoginsMap;
```

My code as below (see **WHAT SHOULD BE INSERTED HERE TO SUPPORT APPLE ID SOCIAL LOGIN** placeholder)

```
        // The parameters required to intialize the Cognito Credentials object.
        const params = {
          AccountId: awsConfig.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID,
          RoleArn: awsConfig.IAM_ROLE_ARN,
          IdentityPoolId: awsConfig.COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
          Logins: { }
        };

        params.Logins[<WHAT SHOULD BE INSERTED HERE TO SUPPORT APPLE ID SOCIAL LOGIN>] = accessToken;
        // set the Amazon Cognito region
        AWS.config.region = awsConfig.AWS_REGION;
        // initialize the Credentials object with our parameters
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(params);

        (AWS.config.credentials as AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials).get((err: AWSError) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          else {
            const COGNITO_IDENTITY_ID = (AWS.config.credentials as AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials).identityId;
            awsConfig.COGNITO_IDENTITY_ID = COGNITO_IDENTITY_ID;
            this.share.cognitoIdentityId = COGNITO_IDENTITY_ID;
            resolve();
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create Apple provider in OpenID or SAML provider if Apple support them. This is example for config Auth0 as OpenID provider and connect with Cognito: https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/integrating-auth0-amazon-cognito-mobile-apps

Comment: The AWS support says that this is not supported yet - see https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3039. What is interesting is that when I picked some guessed value 'www.apple.com' just to try I’m getting "Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName" error which looks like this is not wrong and not supported. But when I tried 'appleid.apple.com' as you suggested I got "Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool" which looks like this is supported but AWS Cognito is not configured yet

Comment: OK. So you need create Apple provider in OpenID or SAML provider if Apple support them. This is example for config Auth0 as OpenID provider and connect with Cognito: https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/integrating-auth0-amazon-cognito-mobile-apps

Comment: After trying several options I still can not make it to work. Even though Amazon claims that they support Apple ID it seems that this is limited and some scenarios are still not supported.

Answer (score 0):

From an AWS Blog:

"One work around is to configure a user pool to use Sign in with Apple and have a User Pool client that only allows Sign in with Apple. You can then treat that user pool client as an authentication provider for an identity pool. You can add additional rules to the user pool authentication to ensure only users that signed using Sign in with Apple can assume the appropriate role."

But it is not entirely clear what the steps are for this as it isn't clear what a "User Pool Client" is.  Perhaps they meant "User Pool App Client".  Anyone get the gist of what is meant?